# keypress to delete value in 'open' datefield and close related datepicker

Tags: extjs, datepicker

I have an ExtJS form.field.Date as below;

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    name: 'X_Cut_Process_Completed_Date',
    format: 'd M Y',
    startDay: 1,
    allowBlank: true,
    editable: false,
    listeners: {
        specialkey: function(field, e){
            if (e.getKey() == e.DELETE) {
                field.setValue('');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been asked to implement an event that catches the Delete key while the `datefield` is being edited (with the associated `datepicker` open), that clears the value for the `datefield` and closes the `datepicker`. The existing `specialkey` listener only clears the value while the `datefield` is NOT being edited.

**How do I implement a listener that closes a `datefield`'s `datepicker` and clear the `datefield`'s value simultaneously?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE]

You can get the picker and hide it:

```
field.getPicker().hide()
```

I have tested it and it works. To test it for yoursef:

1. navigate to http://extjs.eu/software/form-field-icon-plugin/
2. in console type:

   ```
   Ext.ComponentQuery.query('datefield')[0].on('specialkey', function(field, e){
   if(e.getKey() === e.DELETE) {
       field.getPicker().hide();
       field.setValue('');
   }
   ```

   });

Now open the picker in the date field, type something and press delete. Both the field is cleared and the picker is hidden.

Comment: Where do I place this? I placed it in the `specialkey` listener (after `field.setValue('');`) and it does nothing when I have the datepicker open.

Comment: Listener does not run?

Comment: The listener runs, just not when I have the datepicker open.

Comment: Updated the answer, see if you can test it that way.

Comment: Your updated answer requires keyboard input to be entered in order for it to close the datepicker. If you do not enter a value into the field, it does not work; this is problematic for me, as the field is set to 'editable: false', meaning there is no chance to enter text for this to work.

Comment: Ah sooo. Then you must install the listener on the picker, not on the field.

Comment: How do I install the picker on the field? Can I getPicker() on the expand listener, and apply a listener to it that way?

Comment: Yes, you call field.getPicker() that returns the picker and then you install event listener on it. field.getPicker().on(.....)

Comment: I've had to add a keybinding on the datefield on focus, but other than that I've managed to make this work. Thanks for the help.