# Adding key press event to ExtJS DatePicker

Tags: extjs, datepicker, listener

Following from my question regarding setting a `datefield` to delete its value and close its `datepicker` when 'delete' is pressed and the `datepicker` is open ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607316/keypress-to-delete-value-in-open-datefield-and-close-related-datepicker)), I was directed to add a `keypress` or `specialkey` listener on the ExtJS `datepicker` in question.

Unfortunately, there is no capacity for a `datepicker` to handle `specialkey` or `keypress` events listed in the documentation, and attempts at just adding them anyway do not work.

**How do I add the `specialkey` or `keypress` event to an ExtJS `datepicker`?**

Apologies in advance if there is a more generalised question/answer for this; I don't know what to search for to get the relevant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer -

Given a datefield, add the following listeners:

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    name: 'datefield_1',
    [other configs]
    listeners: {
        specialkey: function(field, e){
            if (e.getKey() == e.DELETE) {
                field.setValue('');
            }
        },
        focus: function(field, the, e){
            addKeyMap(field, the, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then add a function that I've called addKeyMap for brevity:

```
function addKeyMap(field, the, e){
    var picker = field.getPicker();
    picker.keyNav.map.addBinding({
        key: Ext.EventObject.DELETE,
        fn: function(keyCode, e) {
            field.setValue('');
            picker.hide();
        },
        scope: this,
        defaultEventAction: 'preventDefault'
    });
}
```

The `addKeyMap` ensures that regardless of the datefield being selected, as long as it has the listener attached, it will ensure the keybinding is present on the datefield, allowing for the desired behaviour.

There may be a more elegant answer to this, but I haven't found one.

Answer (score 0):

Not much more elegant than your solution, but maybe a bit more intuitive without the map.

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    (...)
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function() {                    
            var me = this;
            this.getPicker().on('afterrender', function() {
                this.el.on('keydown', me.nOnDatepickerKeydown, me); // add key listener to datepicker
            });
        }
    },
    nOnDatepickerKeydown: function(e) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case e.DELETE:
                this.setValue(null); // remove value
                this.getPicker().hide(); // hide datepicker
                this.focus(); // focus datefield
                e.preventDefault(); // stop default key event
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I had the same problem trying to fix the space key (should theoretically [select current date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date-cfg-showToday)) functionality ([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15cj)).